# How can I integrate graphs and JPEG images with RAVE Reports?

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I really love RAVE Reports in creating multiple reports especially with formulas and accounting systems... but recently I am having problems with integrating JPEG Pictures and Graphs with my newly Delphi Language developed Little ERP System. I bought some JPEG Components but it seems problematic.

I also experienced some irregularities with my RAVE Reports now. When I run my program then try to preview some reports, it seems to be running fine, but when I close the program, the EXE file is still in the taskbar. I need to ctrl-alt-delete first for me to use Report Previews normally. If I don't, RAVE REPORT ERROR message will appear everytime I click the PRINT button; it says "STREAM READ ERROR" even though I used to "FreeAndNil" to free the memory stream when Report Preview Form closes. When I tried to run the My Applications without previewing RAVE reports, the program closes perfectly.

Any suggestions and recommendations will be an enormous help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, JonDave.  Quick note about how we do things here.  StackOverflow is meant to be a public Q&A repository, and so posting an email and asking for replies there sort of goes against the spirit of the site.  If someone's going to answer your question, it'll go on this page for anyone to see, sort of like a forum.

Comment: It seems like you're reporting three separate and distinct problems. One is about showing a JPEG on the report. (Note that you haven't actually told what problem you're having, merely that you're "having problems.") The second is that your program doesn't really go away when you close it. The third is something about stream read errors that you get in a separate program. Please ask about each of these issues in **separate questions**. It will allow people to give better answers about the issues they know about, and it will let you be more specific about each of your problems.

Comment: WTS .Welcome to StackOverflow. WTF

Answer (score 0):

There's a demo of JPG printing in the tips & tricks area. I have used it, and I have also extended it to work with PNG.  I don't have that code handy now...  But the jpg example should get you going.
Here's the link to their article with code:
http://www.nevrona.com/LinkClick.aspx?link=112&tabid=71&mid=480

Comment: I know it is an old post but the link is no longer valid.